# UK visa for my wife

Tags: visas, uk

I have been traveling to Scotland for 2 months on a business visa.
I want my wife to join me two weeks after I reach there.
She is a homemaker and is not working.
Can you please suggest which visa she has to apply and what documents are required?

Comment: What's her nationality?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you normally reside outside the UK and you mean you want her to temporarily visit you while you are visiting on business, she will need to apply for a [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa). On page 3 of that link you will find details of the documents required.

Bear in mind that if she isn't earning a wage you will need to provide enough evidence to satisfy the UK authorities that she intends to return to her home country after the visit.